# chai eql reports equal arrays as different

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mocha.js, chai

I am testing a function in a node.js program, which should save some data to a mongo database. I am using mocha, chai and should.

In the schema, I have defined the data to be saved as

```
data: [{type: Number, min: 0}]
```

The test saves the array `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` to the database, then `find`s it again, and compares what it found with the array that was saved. The test is

```
result.data.should.eql([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
```

The test result is

```
Uncaught AssertionError: expected [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
to deeply equal [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

According to [this chai.js example](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#members-section), comparing arrays this way should work just fine.

When I test the result with `result.data.should.deep.include.members([1,2,3,4,5,6]);`, the test passes just as expected.

Can anyone explain to me why this is not working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mongoose decorates Arrays with a lot of its own methods. You won't see these when you do `console.log(result.data)`, but [deep-eql](https://github.com/chaijs/deep-eql) (the library that Chai uses to do deep equality) will consider them when doing comparison. This is why the test fails when you use `.eql()`: you are comparing a special Mongoose Array to a plain vanilla Array.

Rather, if you did

```
result.data.toJSON().should.eql([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
```

your test would pass as you expect.

The `.members()` assertion goes through a [different code path](https://github.com/NickHeiner/chai/commit/a5441915945c6589b9a5ba4d21631de3854b12b2#diff-cee0d57e893bb06a9c55e65f14c03cfdR1547), which is why it happens to work.

As an aside, the example that worked for you doesn't do exactly what you want, it is a superset test. What you actually want is:

```
result.data.should.have.members([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
```